# Microsoft Graph API to create shared mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

How to create shared mailbox from MS Graph API And how to convert user mailbox to shared mailbox?
From existing create user POST query, I could just create user and not mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a mailbox is not possible via the Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Can we convert the user mailbox to shared mailbox via Graph API? Is this possible?